# How to make this rectangle a node (TikZ)?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have drawn a rectangle with a fixed position:

```
\[\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[thick] (3,1) rectangle (5,3);  
\end{tikzpicture}\]
```

I would like to make it a `node` with a name (for instance `rec`), so that other elements later could be positioned with regards to it, for instance:

```
\node (elli) [ellipse, below=1cm of rec] {...};
```

Does anyone know how to make the rectangle above a node?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

You can specify the `minimum height` and `minimum width` for a node. In conjunction with `draw`, you'll end up with a rectangle with the specified dimensions:

```
\node (rect) at (4,2) [draw,thick,minimum width=2cm,minimum height=2cm] {};
```

Comment: Here, iiuc (rect) is the label, so what indicates the shape ? Is rectangle simply the default for draw ?

Comment: @Nikana: yes, exactly,  rectangle is the default shape.

Comment: Actually explicitly setting `[rectangle]` is also possible, to restore the default if it was overriden.

Comment: How to make this rectangle fixed sized, and still containing the texts?

Comment: A problem with this approach is that you cannot use the `[scale=…]` option: that does not affect the minimum width/height.

Answer (score 16):

Another solution with `fit` library. Following example shows how to use two opposite corner coordinates to define an rectangular node.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{fit}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[help lines] (0,0) grid (6,4);
    \fill[red] (3,1) circle (1pt) node[below left] {(3,1)} (5,3) circle (1pt) node[above right] {(5,3)};
    \node[fit={(3,1) (5,3)}, inner sep=0pt, draw=blue, thick] (rect) {};
    \draw[red] (rect.east) to[out=0,in=-90] (rect.south);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You can define a node and put the rectagle inside. Then you can add more objets as nodes with relative posititions.

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=5]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \node(cuadrado){
            \tikz {\draw[thick] (3,1) rectangle ++(2,2);}
        };

        % Text inside the rectangle
        \node[at={($(cuadrado.center)$)},anchor=center] (texto) {asd asd asd};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Nesting `tikzpicture` environments should be avoided whenever possible and can be avoided in very nearly almost all cases. Since it can be easily avoided here, this is really not a good solution.

Comment: I would agree that it would be nice if this did work, though. On occasion, it would make life so much simpler! ;)